# Count comparisons and swaps in simple sort program

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have an assignment I need a little help with. We have to pick two sort algorithms in C and compare both on efficiency. I have written the following code but I am not sure if the comparisons are right. I think the swaps is OK. I am new enough to this so be gentle if you see any obvious faults.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 20


int main(void)
{
 //Declare variables
int i,x,y,temp;
int comparsioncounter=0;
int swapcounter=0;
//Assign values to our array. I didn’t use random numbers so we could compare the two methods
int array[MAX]= {3,1,5,8,7,13,17,34,22,31,28,2,17,44,23,67,32,9,12,30};

//start clock to time execution time
clock_t start, end;
start = clock();
printf("Unsorted array\n");
//print unsorted array
for(i=0; i<MAX;i++){
printf("%d ",array[i]);
}
printf("\n");
//Our sort algorithm
for (x=0; x<MAX; x++){  
    for(i=0;i<MAX-1;i++){
        //counter to keep track of how many times the comparison loops
        comparsioncounter++;
        if(array[i]>array[i+1])
        {
            temp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[i+1];
            array[i+1]=temp;
            //Counter to keep track of how many times the comparison loops
            swapcounter++;
        }
    }

}
          //print sorted array
    printf("\nSorted array\n");
    for(i=0; i<MAX;i++){
    printf("%d ",array[i]);

}
//Print out number of comparsions and swaps
printf("\n\nNumber of comparsions is %d\n", comparsioncounter);
printf("Number of swaps is %d", swapcounter);
end = clock();
//print out execution time
printf("\nTime taken in seconds: %.5lf\n", ((double)(end - start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a very small sets of inputs, do the calculations *on paper*, and then compare to what you get in your program. If both are the same then you are probably correct, else there's something wrong.

Comment: `x<20;..i<19` : 20*19=`380`

Comment: If i reduce the array to a size of 4. Swaps is counting correctly but comparisons is returning 16. I do not think this is correct

Comment: You should move `begin = clock();` and `end = clock();` so that they cover just the algorithm (the loop).

Comment: If you are trying to measure performance, be aware that the precision of clock() is influenced by the system clock resolution (typically something between 1 and 15 ms). If you are in Linux you can use more efficient ways to do this, if you are in Windows you should at least make sure to force the system clock to the 1 ms resolution.

Comment: if size of `4` , 4*3=`12`

Comment: I am on windows. an you advise on how to this please. Thanks for the help everyone by they way.

Comment: You do `MAX * (MAX - 1)` number of loops, and increase `comparisoncounter` every inner loop (i.e. `MAX * (MAX - 1)` times). The program you show *can't* set `comparisoncounter` to `16` if `MAX` is `4`.

Comment: Its returning 16 if i reduce the array to size of 4.

Answer (score 1):

seems to be correct.

Another way of doing so where it's maybe more apparent would be writing a comparison and a swap function that count their counters up.

like this:

```
static unsigned comps = 0, swaps = 0;

int compare(int l, int r)
{
  comps++;
  return (l > r);
}

void swap(int *l, int *r)
{
  swaps++;
  int t = *l;
  *l = *r;
  *r = t;
}
```

and then use them instead.